# Why do we associate discrete values to data from a continuous distribution?

Tags: statistics

If we think about a random variable following a discrete distribution then I can accept the association of a discrete value in data to the variable. For example, let's talk about n independent basketball shots each with probability p of making it into the hoop. The number of shots that make it in is distributed $X \sim Binomial(n,p)$. In theoretical sports leagues we could report on this number: player A made 5 shots out of 12, and so forth, etc. So in this example the variable crystallizes to some discrete value $X =5$, or we associate a discrete value to this data from a discrete distribution.

My point of confusion is now if we consider some data or crystallization of variables from continuous distributions. The immediate example I can think of is grades on an exam. Professors always say that there was a normal distribution of grades. But when you actually refer to the grade received on your exam or my exam, these are discrete numbers. Yet, still, we associate that discrete outcome of a grade to some continuous random variable!

It is well known in probability theory that $P(X=x)=0$ for any continuous variable $X$. That is, the probability that the test score, a continuous random variable that is normally distributed, is ever equal to some discrete value should be $0$. Then how come your score or my score on the exam is some discrete number, like 80 or 90 out of 100? Why are we associating discrete values to data from a continuous distribution? What is the fallacy in logic here? Is this some misnomer that we make when we are not rigorously saying that test scores follow a normal distribution?

Finally, it seems like the concept of a continuously distributed random variable is really intractable to untrained intuition. Could it be some part of developmental psychology that explains it? Let me explain why it seems so to me:

When we say $B \sim Binomial(n,p)$ then we can mean to say that $B$ takes at least some value $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with nonzero probability. But when we say $N \sim Normal(\mu,\sigma^2)$ we mean to say $N$ can never take any value $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with a nonzero probability. This seems very frustrating because at first instinct we use random variables to model outcomes, and by human nature tend to associate outcomes as only discrete. For example, most people's first encounter with distributions of variables will be in grade school when the teacher says "oh, that history exam's grade were on this normal curve" and then pulls up some symmetric bell curve on the projector. Obviously later we learn that instead of just a particular value, we can model the probability that some value falls within an infinitesimal range and that's when the density functions of continuous variables become particularly valuable. But perhaps it's what we learn first that irreversibly colours our instinct?

I hope my point is clear. It seems that in conventional principle we still associate discrete outcomes with continuous variables! Why is that?

Comment: When professors say "there was a normal distribution of grades", perhaps they mean that the distribution of grades informally *approximates* a normal distribution.

Comment: You must try to kick the habit of thinking about discrete points having probabilities under a continuous distribution. (It is an unhelpful self-delusion). One temporary cure is to speak of a 'discrete' normal dist'n, in which each integer $k$ inherits the actual probability of $k \pm .5.$ For lengths, weights, volumes, etc, it is best to express a point in terms of the interval actually intended. In applications, such intervals are not often of "infinitesimal" size, more often of unit sizes. // As in my Answer, discrete dist'ns 'live on' points and continuous ones 'live on' intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a distinction between discrete and continuous random variables
that I think you may find useful.

**Discrete random variable:** Suppose a random variable can take integer values $0, 1, 2, \dots, 10.$ A random variable $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(10, p)$ is an example. Then we specify the distribution of $X$ by somehow
giving the probability that $X$ takes each of these possible values.
This can be done by making a table, making a bar chart, or giving an equation. If $p = 1/2,$ then the equation is 
$$P(X = k) = {10 \choose k}(1/2)^n,$$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 10.$

In R statistical software, I can
make a table of probabilities correct to ten decimal places as follows (you can ignore the row numbers in brackets
 `[ ]`.)

```
k = 0:10; PDF = dbinom(k, 10, .5)
cbind(k, PDF)
       k          PDF
 [1,]  0 0.0009765625
 [2,]  1 0.0097656250
 [3,]  2 0.0439453125
 [4,]  3 0.1171875000
 [5,]  4 0.2050781250
 [6,]  5 0.2460937500
 [7,]  6 0.2050781250
 [8,]  7 0.1171875000
 [9,]  8 0.0439453125
[10,]  9 0.0097656250
[11,] 10 0.0009765625
```

And here is a bar chart:

[image]

Whether we give the probabilities by formula, table, or barchart, the
idea is the same: *In order to specify the distribution of a discrete
random variable, we need to give the probability of each possible point value.*

**Continuous random variable.** A beta random variable can take any
value in the interval $(0, 1),$ which is called the *support* $S_X$ of the random variable. We use a density function to specify
the distribution of a continuous random variable. A density function
$f(x)$ has three rules:

(a) $f(x) \ge 0,$ for all $x \in S_X.$

(b) The area under the the density function over $S_X$ must be $1.$ 
Using an integral, this can be stated as $\int_{S_X} f(x)\, dx
= 1.$ For a beta distribution in particular it's $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = 1.$

(c) The probability $P(a < X \le b)$ for $a < b; a,b \in S_X$
 is the area under the density function over the interval $(a,b].$ In terms of an integral, this is can
be written as $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx.$

This means that *we define probabilities only for intervals*
and the probability $P(X = a) = 0$ for any one point $a.$ Hence, intervals $(a,b), [a,b), (a,b],$ and $[a,b]$ (where $a < b)$ all have the same probability.

For example, the density function of the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(2, 1)$ is $f(x) = 2x,$ for $0 < x < 1.$  Clearly, this definition satisfies condition (a), and a simple integration (or some elementary school geometry)
shows that $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 2x\,dx = 1,$ so that (b)
is satisfied.

We can use condition (c) to find $P(0.1 < X < 0.6) = \int_{.1}^{.6} 2x \, dx = 0.35$.

Here is a graph of the density function. The area between the vertical dotted lines is $P(0.1 < X < 0.6).$

[image]

*Note:* For some important continuous distributions, the integration in (c) has
to be done by numerical methods instead of using calculus. The normal
distribution is one of those distributions, which is why we use printed normal tables, statistical calculators or software for finding areas
under a normal curve.

**Distinctions.** Colloquially speaking, discrete distributions 'live on' a finite or countable number of discrete **points**. For $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(10, .5),$ if you want $P(3 \le X \le 5) = 0.5683594.$ then you have to get the probability of this 'interval' by adding the probabilities of the three relevant points (3, 4, and 5).

By contrast, continuous distributions 'live on' **intervals**. If 
$Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(70, 7)$ and you ask for $P(Y = 77),$ then the
technical answer is $0.$ If this distribution is intended to describe
the masses (in kg) of collegiate make swimmers, then maybe by
$P(Y = 77)$ you really mean $P(76.5 < Y \le 77.5).$ Now, *that* is an
*interval* and you can use normal tables or software to find
$P(76.5 < Y \le 77.5) = 0.0346.$

```
diff(pnorm(c(76.5, 77.5), 70, 7))
[1] 0.03456723
```